# ARKit, Recorded Session from RealityComposer, application error (screen frozen after the installing pipeline)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am trying to run the application on the iPad M1 Device pinned to the Xcode debugger.
The scheme has the **Replay data** enabled with the film prerecorded from the very same iPad M1.

Errors:

> 2022-09-19 19:21:52.790061+0100 ARPathFinder[1373:320166] ⛔️⛔️⛔️ ERROR
> [MOVReaderInterface]: Error
> Domain=com.apple.AppleCV3DMOVKit.readererror Code=9 "CVAUserEvent:
> Error Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot
> grab metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknown
> metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'.}"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=CVAUserEvent: Error
> Domain=com.apple.videoeng.streamreaderwarning Code=0 "Cannot grab
> metadata. Unknown metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot grab metadata. Unknown
> metadata stream 'CVAUserEvent'.}} ⛔️⛔️⛔️
>
> 2022-09-19 19:21:54.103813+0100 ARPathFinder[1373:320166] [Session]
> ARSession <0x104f77ec0>: did fail with error: Error
> Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=101 "Required sensor unavailable."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Required sensor unavailable.,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=A required sensor is not available on this
> device.}

I've tried to reload the **mov** video. I tried deleting the app but that does not seem to help.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.